# How can I get the behavior of GNU's readlink -f on a Mac?

Tags: macos, freebsd, sh

On Linux, the `readlink` utility accepts an option `-f` that follows additional links. This doesn't seem to work on Mac and possibly BSD based systems. What would the equivalent be?

Here's some debug information:

```
$ which readlink; readlink -f
/usr/bin/readlink
readlink: illegal option -f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
```

Comment: A bit late, but your question is missing any mentioning of the shell you use. This is relevant, because `readlink` can be a builtin or an external command.

Comment: That would explain the difference perhaps. I'm fairly sure I used bash on both occasions though.

Comment: Why is this option illegal on Macs?

Comment: @CommaToast - if I recall, for the "Unix" portion of the OS, Macs try to stick to POSIX and/or BSD derived tools and utilities. You can install GNU utilities on OS/X or adjust the commands to use "pure" Bourne shell (`/bin/sh` without `bash` extensions). For many developers these days shell scripts =  Linux, GNU utilities and `bash` so portability issues appear.

Comment: I really wish Apple would make OS X support more default linux paths, and address things like this. They could do it without breaking anything, couldn't they?

Comment: @CommaToast Well, they ship with Perl so ++ :-)  ... open Terminal.app and  type: `touch myfile ; ln -s myfile otherfile ; perl -MCwd=abs_path -le 'print abs_path readlink(shift);' otherfile` ... in my case I see:  /Users/cito/myfile`.  Added it to my response below. Cheers.

Comment: @CommaToast GNU's Not Unix :-) Stuff has been added. You can use a solution with `pwd -P` on OS X without installing anything

Comment: @CommaToast `readlink` is GPLv3 and Apple won't touch anything GPLv3 because of the requirement to hand over cryptographic keys to a device in order to modify GPLv3 software on that device. https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html#protecting-your-right-to-tinker It will be one reason the default shell is no longer Bash but Zsh

Comment: @JasonS but FreeBSD has had `readlink -f` since [sometime between 2010 and 2012](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), depending on man page date vs. BSD release date, and that's not a GPL implementation. So Apple is just dragging its heels. And actually, `readlink -f` originated in OpenBSD 2.1 in 1997, as far as I can tell. So the first implementation wasn't even GNU. I can understand it not being in Snow Leopard, but I can't understand it not being in Mavericks/Sierra.

Comment: @WyattWard Fair point. The only Mac I have access to (10.11 Big Sur), man readlink date is 2003. So yeah it could be updated. And as you say not GPLv3 at all, so disregard my earlier comment about it being GPLv3. I was running a bit blind with so many people complaining why Mac OS is not GNU. No it's not. Never will be. But point remains you can get the job done though with `pwd -P` without wishing Mac OS was GNU Linux by using Homebrew. Yes shell scripts are not portable. Not unique to Mac OS.

Comment: macOS 12.3 [supports](https://scriptingosx.com/2022/03/some-cli-updates-in-macos-monterey/) `readlink -f`.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

`readlink -f` does two things:

1. It iterates along a sequence of symlinks until it finds an actual file.
2. It returns that file's *canonicalized* name—i.e., its absolute pathname.

If you want to, you can just build a shell script that uses vanilla readlink behavior to achieve the same thing.  Here's an example.  Obviously you could insert this in your own script where you'd like to call `readlink -f`

```
#!/bin/sh

TARGET_FILE=$1

cd `dirname $TARGET_FILE`
TARGET_FILE=`basename $TARGET_FILE`

# Iterate down a (possible) chain of symlinks
while [ -L "$TARGET_FILE" ]
do
    TARGET_FILE=`readlink $TARGET_FILE`
    cd `dirname $TARGET_FILE`
    TARGET_FILE=`basename $TARGET_FILE`
done

# Compute the canonicalized name by finding the physical path 
# for the directory we're in and appending the target file.
PHYS_DIR=`pwd -P`
RESULT=$PHYS_DIR/$TARGET_FILE
echo $RESULT
```

Note that this doesn't include any error handling.  Of particular importance, it doesn't detect symlink cycles.  A simple way to do this would be to count the number of times you go around the loop and fail if you hit an improbably large number, such as 1,000.

EDITED to use `pwd -P` instead of `$PWD`.

Note that this script expects to be called like `./script_name filename`, no `-f`, change `$1` to `$2` if you want to be able to use with `-f filename` like GNU readlink.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that won't work if a parent dir of the path is a symlink. Eg. if `foo -> /var/cux`, then `foo/bar` won't be resolved, because `bar` isn't a link, although `foo` is.

Comment: Ah.  Yes.  It's not as simple but you can update the above script to deal with that.  I'll edit (rewrite, really) the answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, a link could be anywhere in the path. I guess the script could iterate over each part of the path, but it does become a bit complicated then.

Comment: A link earlier in the path shouldn't matter.  All of the tools and system calls that operate on paths automatically follow symlinks in pathnames.  In testing on my system, the above script and "readlink -f" produce the same results when there is a symlink in the middle of a path---either the argument or in another symlink.  Can you provide an example where it's a problem?

Comment: Yes: `mkdir a; mkdir a/b; mkdir x; ln -s ../a x/y`. Now assuming that the above script is `canonicalize`, running `./canonicalize x/y/b` does not give the same output as `readlink -f x/y/b`.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem is that $PWD is giving us the logical working directory, based in the values in the symlinks that we've followed.  We can get the real physical directory with 'pwd -P'  It should compute it by chasing ".." up to the root of the file system.  I'll update the script in my answer accordingly.

Comment: The answer given duplicates the effort of pwd.

Comment: This answer will not work if the symlink targets "/something/..": the result is "/something/.." (as .. is not a link, we are now in the something directory, and the basename is ..). The result of canonicalization by `readlink -f` is "/".

Comment: Great solution, but it doesn't deal properly with _paths that need escaping_, such as file or directory names with _embedded spaces_. To remedy that, use `cd "$(dirname "$TARGET_FILE")"`  and `TARGET_FILE=$(readlink "$TARGET_FILE")` and `TARGET_FILE=$(basename "$TARGET_FILE")` in the appropriate places in the above code.

Comment: If you want this script to return the path of the file that contains it, you must pass $0 instead of $1 in the first line. ($1 assumes you're trying to get the real path of another file, which you already have a path for).

Comment: that assumes that the file or directory exists, which realpath and readlink deals with

Comment: Should it `cd` back to the original working directory before teardown?

Comment: All paths and filename variables need to be wrapped in quotes, like this: `TARGET_FILE="\`basename "$TARGET_FILE"\`"`

Comment: Need to use `cd -P` to prevent paths like `this/is/a/symlink/..` from breaking

Answer (score 487):

MacPorts and Homebrew provide a *coreutils* package containing `greadlink` (GNU readlink). Credit to Michael Kallweitt post in mackb.com.

```
brew install coreutils

greadlink -f file.txt
```

Comment: If you are calling readlink from places other than bash, another solution would be remove /usr/bin/readlink then create a link to /usr/local/bin/greadlink.

Comment: Please don't, unless you a) write software for your own b) want to mess with others. Write it in such a way that it "just works" for anybody.

Comment: @ching Do this instead in your `.bashrc`: `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

Comment: The question asks for the equivalent on a OS X or BSD system, this doesn't answer that. You'll also have to install Homebrew. You'll also be installing many things apart from GNU Readlink. If you're writing a script for standard OS X installs this answer won't help. You can use a combination of `pwd -P` and the `readlink` on OS X, without installing anything

Comment: **I wanted** the GNU and other utils on my Mac that I believe do so well, without the prefix, and easily accessible from my user's `PATH`.  Did the above starting with `brew install <package>  --default-names`.  Many times a question on this site has been answered slightly, or more so, outside the technical requirements of the asker, but within the similar situation, and has still been very helpful.  https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: @Pysis Not to discredit your choices and what you find useful, and that this answer may be a good answer to a different question, but I would still contend this is not a good answer to this particular question.

Comment: then do `alias readlink=greadlink` in your rc file to continue using the name you're used to.

Answer (score 47):

You may be interested in [`realpath(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/realpath.3.html), or Python's [`os.path.realpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath).  The two aren't exactly the same; the C library call requires that intermediary path components exist, while the Python version does not.

```
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 miles    wheel  0 Jul 11 21:08 a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 miles    wheel  1 Jul 11 20:49 b -> a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 miles    wheel  1 Jul 11 20:49 c -> b
$ python -c 'import os,sys;print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))' c
/private/tmp/foo/a
```

I know you said you'd prefer something more lightweight than another scripting language, but just in case compiling a binary is insufferable, you can use Python and ctypes (available on Mac OS X 10.5) to wrap the library call:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import ctypes, sys

libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.dylib')
libc.realpath.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
libc.__error.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
libc.strerror.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

def realpath(path):
    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1024) # PATH_MAX
    if libc.realpath(path, buffer):
        return buffer.value
    else:
        errno = libc.__error().contents.value
        raise OSError(errno, "%s: %s" % (libc.strerror(errno), buffer.value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print realpath(sys.argv[1])
```

Ironically, the C version of this script ought to be shorter. :)

Comment: Yes, `realpath` is indeed what I want. But it seems rather awkward that I have to compile a binary to get this function from a shell script.

Comment: Why not use the Python one-liner in the shell script then? (Not so different from a one-line call to `readlink` itself, is it?)

Comment: `python -c "import os,sys; print(os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(sys.argv[1])))" "${1}"` works with paths like `'~/.symlink'`

Comment: @troelskin I didn't realize Perl, Python, *etc.* were "allowed"  !!  ... in that case I'm going to add`perl -MCwd=abs_path -le  'print abs_path readlink(shift);'` to my answer :-)

Answer (score 40):

A simple one-liner in perl that's sure to work almost everywhere without any external dependencies:

```
perl -MCwd -e 'print Cwd::abs_path shift' ~/non-absolute/file
```

Will dereference symlinks.

Usage in a script could be like this:

```
readlinkf(){ perl -MCwd -e 'print Cwd::abs_path shift' "$1";}
ABSPATH="$(readlinkf ./non-absolute/file)"
```

Comment: to get a trailing newline, add `-l`, like `perl -MCwd -le 'print Cwd::abs_path shift' ~/non-absolute/file`

Answer (score 32):

You might need both **a portable, pure shell implementation**, and **unit-test coverage**, as the number of edge-cases for something like this is *non-trivial*.

See [my project on Github](https://github.com/mkropat/sh-realpath) for tests and full code. What follows is a synopsis of the implementation:

As Keith Smith astutely points out, `readlink -f` does two things: 1) resolves symlinks recursively, and 2) canonicalizes the result, hence:

```
realpath() {
    canonicalize_path "$(resolve_symlinks "$1")"
}
```

First, the symlink resolver implementation:

```
resolve_symlinks() {
    local dir_context path
    path=$(readlink -- "$1")
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        dir_context=$(dirname -- "$1")
        resolve_symlinks "$(_prepend_path_if_relative "$dir_context" "$path")"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$1"
    fi
}

_prepend_path_if_relative() {
    case "$2" in
        /* ) printf '%s\n' "$2" ;;
         * ) printf '%s\n' "$1/$2" ;;
    esac 
}
```

Note that this is a slightly simplified version of [the full implementation](https://github.com/mkropat/sh-realpath/blob/master/realpath.sh). **The full implementation adds a small check for symlink cycles**, as well as massages the output a bit.

Finally, the function for canonicalizing a path:

```
canonicalize_path() {
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        _canonicalize_dir_path "$1"
    else
        _canonicalize_file_path "$1"
    fi
}   

_canonicalize_dir_path() {
    (cd "$1" 2>/dev/null && pwd -P) 
}           
        
_canonicalize_file_path() {
    local dir file
    dir=$(dirname -- "$1")
    file=$(basename -- "$1")
    (cd "$dir" 2>/dev/null && printf '%s/%s\n' "$(pwd -P)" "$file")
}
```

That's it, more or less. Simple enough to paste into your script, but tricky enough that you'd be crazy to rely on any code that doesn't have unit tests for your use cases.

Comment: This is not POSIX - it uses the non-POSIX `local` keyword

Comment: This is not equivalent to `readlink -f`, nor of `realpath`. Assuming a Mac with the coreutils formula installed (so with `greadlink` available), try this with `ln -s ~/Documents /tmp/linkeddir`; `greadlink -f /tmp/linkeddir/..` prints your home directory (it resolved the `/tmp/linkeddir` link before applying the `..` parent dir ref), but your code produces `/private/tmp/` as `/tmp/linkeddir/..` is not a symlink, but `-d /tmp/linkeddir/..` is true and so `cd /tmp/linkeddir/..` takes you to `/tmp`, whose canonical path is `/private/tmp`. Your code does what `realpath -L` does, instead.

Comment: Above problem can be solved with `cd -P` in _canonicalize_dir_path

Answer (score 27):

1. Install homebrew
2. Run "brew install coreutils"
3. Run "greadlink -f path"

greadlink is the gnu readlink that implements -f. You can use macports or others as well, I prefer homebrew.

Comment: I can't see any difference to the answer given in 2010 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031502/695671

Comment: If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
  PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

Answer (score 21):

I made a script called realpath personally which looks a little something like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: You should change that to `sys.argv[1]` if you want the script to print the realpath of the first argument. `sys.argv[0]` just prints the real path of the pyton script itself, which is not very useful.

Comment: Here's the alias version, for `~/.profile`: `alias realpath="python -c 'import os, sys; print os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])'"`

Comment: Great answer, and great one-liner @jwhitlock.  Since the OP cited `readlink -f`, here's a modified version of @jwhitlock 's alias to support possible `-f` flag:  `alias realpath="python -c 'import os, sys; print os.path.realpath(sys.argv[2] if sys.argv[1] == \"-f\" else sys.argv[1])'"`

Answer (score 14):

What about this?

```
function readlink() {
  DIR="${1%/*}"
  (cd "$DIR" && echo "$(pwd -P)")
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me; I need to parse paths like `../../../` -> `/`

Comment: this can't work if you have a symlink `/usr/bin/` for example like the `alternatives` system likes to have.

Comment: Does not work for individual files, only directories.  GNU readlink works with directories, files, symlinks, etc.

Comment: This actually does the job without reinventing the wheel. May not cover 100% cases but easily beats the other solutions for me.

Comment: You probably want to do `DIR=$(dirname "$1")` instead.

Answer (score 12):

**Implementation**

1. Install brew

Follow the instructions at https://brew.sh/

2. Install the coreutils package

`brew install coreutils`

3. Create an Alias or Symlink

3a. Create an an alias (per user)

You can place your alias in ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, or wherever you are used to keeping your bash aliases. I personally keep mine in ~/.bashrc

`alias readlink=greadlink`

3b. Create a symbolic link (system wide)

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/greadlink /usr/local/bin/readlink` (credit: Izana)

This will create a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin while keeping the original readlink binary in tact. It works because the search for readlink will return 2 results. But the second in /usr/local/bin will take precedence.

e.g.  `which readlink`

To undo this change simply `unlink  /usr/local/bin/readlink`

**Additional Tools**

You can create similar aliases or symlinks for other coreutils such as gmv, gdu, gdf, and so on. But beware that the GNU behavior on a mac machine may be confusing to others used to working with native coreutils, or may behave in unexpected ways on your mac system.

**Explanation**

coreutils is a `brew` package that installs GNU/Linux core utilities which correspond to the Mac OSX implementation of them so that you can use those

You may find programs or utilties on your mac osx system which seem similar to Linux coreutils ("Core Utilities") yet they differ in some ways (such as having different flags).

This is because the Mac OSX implementation of these tools are different. To get the original GNU/Linux-like behavior you can install the `coreutils` package via the `brew` package management system.

This will install corresponding core utilities, prefixed by `g`. E.g. for `readlink`, you will find a corresponding `greadlink` program.

In order to make `readlink` perform like the GNU `readlink` (`greadlink`) implementation, you can create a simple alias or symbolic link after you install coreutils.

Comment: This solution does not work system-wide.

Comment: Thanks @KevinC I expanded my answer to include system wide option and explanation.

Answer (score 12):

A lazy way that works for me,

```
$ brew install coreutils
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/greadlink /usr/local/bin/readlink
$ which readlink
/usr/local/bin/readlink
/usr/bin/readlink
```

Comment: Scroll no further: this is the most concise and best answer on macOS.

Comment: Thank you, does not force me to remove original one. and `/user/local/bin/` takes precedence over `/user/bin/` file. Easy to undo by deleting `/usr/local/bin/readlink` link

Comment: Works system wide.

Answer (score 6):

[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat) and [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) have a version of `stat`derived from NetBSD.

You can adjust the output with format switches (see the manual pages at the links above).

```
%  cd  /service
%  ls -tal 
drwxr-xr-x 22 root wheel 27 Aug 25 10:41 ..
drwx------  3 root wheel  8 Jun 30 13:59 .s6-svscan
drwxr-xr-x  3 root wheel  5 Jun 30 13:34 .
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root wheel 30 Dec 13 2013 clockspeed-adjust -> /var/service/clockspeed-adjust
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root wheel 29 Dec 13 2013 clockspeed-speed -> /var/service/clockspeed-speed
% stat -f%R  clockspeed-adjust
/var/service/clockspeed-adjust
% stat -f%Y  clockspeed-adjust
/var/service/clockspeed-adjust
```

Some OS X versions of `stat`  may lack the `-f%R` option for formats. In this case `-stat -f%Y` may suffice. The `-f%Y` option will show the target of a symlink, whereas `-f%R` shows the absolute pathname corresponding to the file.

**EDIT:**

If you're able to use Perl (Darwin/OS X comes installed with recent verions of `perl`) then:

```
perl -MCwd=abs_path -le 'print abs_path readlink(shift);' linkedfile.txt
```

will work.

Comment: This is true on FreeBSD 10, but not on OS X 10.9.

Comment: Good catch. The [stat manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) cited is for OS/X 10.9. The `R` option to `-f%` is missing. Possibly `stat -f%Y` gives the desired output. I will adjust the answer. Note that the `stat` tool appeared in FreeBSD in version 4.10 and NetBSD in version 1.6.

Comment: Perl command does not work correctly on 10.15.  Give it a file in current directory and it gives the current directory (without the file).

Comment: `stat -f%Y` is equivalent to `readlink` on MacOS: prints target if argument is symlink or prints nothing and exit with error. The GNU `readlink -f` prints a path no matter if argument is symlink or not. Thus `stat -f%Y` is no way behaves like `readlink -f`.

Comment: FreeBSD has had `readlink -f` [since 2012](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), NetBSD [since 2007](https://man.netbsd.org/NetBSD-4.0/x86/readlink.1), and OpenBSD [since 1997](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/readlink/readlink.c?rev=1.10). Apple is just using ten year old utilities and dragging its heels.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to solve this problem and enable the functionality of readlink on Mac w/ Homebrew installed or FreeBSD is to install 'coreutils' package.  May also be necessary on certain Linux distributions and other POSIX OS.

For example, in FreeBSD 11, I installed by invoking:

`# pkg install coreutils`

On MacOS with Homebrew, the command would be:

`$ brew install coreutils`

Not really sure why the other answers are so complicated, that's all there is to it. The files aren't in a different place, they're just not installed yet.

Comment: `brew install coreutils --with-default-names` to be more specific. Or you'll end up with "greadlink" instead...

Comment: I can't see any difference to the answers from 2010 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031502/695671 and 2012 https://stackoverflow.com/a/9918368/695671 The question is actually "... on Mac and possibly BSD based systems. What would the equivalent be?" I don't believe this is a very good answer to that question. Many reasons, but you may be targeting Mac OS machines without ability to install anything. `pwd -P` is pretty simple but it disappears amongst many other answers, including repeated ones, hence the downvote.

Comment: FreeBSD had `readlink -f` since [five years before you wrote this answer](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html). So I'd suggest removing that part. Otherwise, good suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a portable shell function that should work in *ANY* Bourne comparable shell.
It will resolve the relative path punctuation ".. or ." and dereference symbolic links.

If for some reason you do not have a realpath(1) command, or readlink(1) this can be aliased.

```sh
which realpath || alias realpath='real_path'
```

Enjoy:

```sh
real_path () {
  OIFS=$IFS
  IFS='/'
  for I in $1
  do
    # Resolve relative path punctuation.
    if [ "$I" = "." ] || [ -z "$I" ]
      then continue
    elif [ "$I" = ".." ]
      then FOO="${FOO%%/${FOO##*/}}"
           continue
      else FOO="${FOO}/${I}"
    fi

    ## Resolve symbolic links
    if [ -h "$FOO" ]
    then
    IFS=$OIFS
    set `ls -l "$FOO"`
    while shift ;
    do
      if [ "$1" = "->" ]
        then FOO=$2
             shift $#
             break
      fi
    done
    IFS='/'
    fi
  done
  IFS=$OIFS
  echo "$FOO"
}
```

also, just in case anybody is interested here is how to implement basename and dirname in 100% pure shell code:

```sh
## http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/dirname.html
# the dir name excludes the least portion behind the last slash.
dir_name () {
  echo "${1%/*}"
}

## http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/basename.html
# the base name excludes the greatest portion in front of the last slash.
base_name () {
  echo "${1##*/}"
}
```

You can find updated version of this shell code at my google site: http://sites.google.com/site/jdisnard/realpath

EDIT:
This code is licensed under the terms of the 2-clause (freeBSD style) license.
A copy of the license may be found by following the above hyperlink to my site.

Comment: The real_path returns /filename instead of /path/to/filename on Mac OS X Lion in the bash shell.

Comment: @Barry The same happens on OSX Snow Leopard. Worse, successive calls to real_path() concatenate output!

Comment: @Dominique: not surprising, since the inside of the function isn't run in its own subshell ... ugly and fragile indeed.

Answer (score 4):

echo $(cd $(dirname file1) ; pwd -P)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it solves the problem out-of-the-box, without writing complicated functions or installing additional dependencies.  
*man readlink* on Linux: `-f  canonicalize by following every symlink...`, *man pwd* on macOS: `-P  Display the physical current workign directory (all symbolic links resolved)`

Comment: The only portable answer that doesn't involve writing some crazy amount of extra code.

Comment: Produces wrong output if `file1` is a symlink.

Answer (score 3):

**Begin Update**

This is such a frequent problem that we have put together a Bash 4 library for free use (MIT License) called **realpath-lib**.  This is designed to emulate **readlink -f** by default and includes two test suites to verify (1) that it works for a given unix system and (2) against **readlink -f** if installed (but this is not required).  Additionally, it can be used to investigate, identify and unwind deep, broken symlinks and circular references, so it can be a useful tool for diagnosing deeply-nested physical or symbolic directory and file problems.  It can be found at [github.com](https://github.com/AsymLabs/realpath-lib) or [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/AsymLabs/realpath-lib).

**End Update**

Another very compact and efficient solution that does not rely on anything but Bash is:

```
function get_realpath() {

    [[ ! -f "$1" ]] && return 1 # failure : file does not exist.
    [[ -n "$no_symlinks" ]] && local pwdp='pwd -P' || local pwdp='pwd' # do symlinks.
    echo "$( cd "$( echo "${1%/*}" )" 2>/dev/null; $pwdp )"/"${1##*/}" # echo result.
    return 0 # success

}
```

This also includes an environment setting `no_symlinks` that provides the ability to resolve symlinks to the physical system.  As long as `no_symlinks` is set to something, ie `no_symlinks='on'` then symlinks will be resolved to the physical system.  Otherwise they will be applied (the default setting).

This should work on any system that provides Bash, and will return a Bash compatible exit code for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There are already a lot of answers, but none worked for me... So this is what I'm using now.

```
readlink_f() {
  local target="$1"
  [ -f "$target" ] || return 1 #no nofile

  while [ -L "$target" ]; do
    target="$(readlink "$target")" 
  done
  echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$target")"; pwd -P)/$target"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the `$target` is a path, it only works if it's a file.

Answer (score 2):

Since my work is used by people with non-BSD Linux as well as macOS, I've opted for using these aliases in our build scripts (`sed` included since it has similar issues):

```
##
# If you're running macOS, use homebrew to install greadlink/gsed first:
#   brew install coreutils
#
# Example use:
#   # Gets the directory of the currently running script
#   dotfilesDir=$(dirname "$(globalReadlink -fm "$0")")
#   alias al='pico ${dotfilesDir}/aliases.local'
##

function globalReadlink () {
  # Use greadlink if on macOS; otherwise use normal readlink
  if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then
    greadlink "$@"
  else
    readlink "$@"
  fi
}

function globalSed () {
  # Use gsed if on macOS; otherwise use normal sed
  if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then
    gsed "$@"
  else
    sed "$@"
  fi
}
```

Optional check you could add to automatically install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) + [coreutils](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) dependencies:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  # Install brew if needed
  if [ -z "$(which brew)" ]; then 
    /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"; 
  fi
  # Check for coreutils
  if [ -z "$(brew ls coreutils)" ]; then
    brew install coreutils
  fi
fi
```

I suppose to be truly "global" it needs to check others...but that probably comes close to the 80/20 mark.

Answer (score 2):

**POSIX compliant `readlink -f` implementation for POSIX shell scripts**

https://github.com/ko1nksm/readlinkf

This is POSIX compliant (no bashism). It uses neither `readlink` nor `realpath`. I have verified that it is exactly the same by comparing with GNU `readlink -f` (see [test results](https://cirrus-ci.com/github/ko1nksm/readlinkf/master)). It has error handling and good performance. You can safely replace from `readlink -f`. The license is CC0, so you can use it for any project.

**This code is adopted in the [bats-core](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core/pull/312) project.**

```sh
# POSIX compliant version
readlinkf_posix() {
  [ "${1:-}" ] || return 1
  max_symlinks=40
  CDPATH='' # to avoid changing to an unexpected directory

  target=$1
  [ -e "${target%/}" ] || target=${1%"${1##*[!/]}"} # trim trailing slashes
  [ -d "${target:-/}" ] && target="$target/"

  cd -P . 2>/dev/null || return 1
  while [ "$max_symlinks" -ge 0 ] && max_symlinks=$((max_symlinks - 1)); do
    if [ ! "$target" = "${target%/*}" ]; then
      case $target in
        /*) cd -P "${target%/*}/" 2>/dev/null || break ;;
        *) cd -P "./${target%/*}" 2>/dev/null || break ;;
      esac
      target=${target##*/}
    fi

    if [ ! -L "$target" ]; then
      target="${PWD%/}${target:+/}${target}"
      printf '%s\n' "${target:-/}"
      return 0
    fi

    # `ls -dl` format: "%s %u %s %s %u %s %s -> %s\n",
    #   <file mode>, <number of links>, <owner name>, <group name>,
    #   <size>, <date and time>, <pathname of link>, <contents of link>
    # https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html
    link=$(ls -dl -- "$target" 2>/dev/null) || break
    target=${link#*" $target -> "}
  done
  return 1
}
```

Please refer to the latest code. It may some fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, I suppose.  I was motivated to develop this specifically because my Fedora scripts weren't working on the Mac.  The problem is dependencies and Bash.  Macs don't have them, or if they do, they are often somewhere else (another path).  Dependency path manipulation in a cross-platform Bash script is a headache at best and a security risk at worst - so it's best to avoid their use, if possible.

The function get_realpath() below is simple, Bash-centric, and no dependencies are required.  I uses only the Bash builtins **echo** and **cd**.  It is also fairly secure, as everything gets tested at each stage of the way and it returns error conditions.

If you don't want to follow symlinks, then put **set -P** at the front of the script, but otherwise **cd** should resolve the symlinks by default.  It's been tested with file arguments that are {absolute | relative | symlink | local} and it returns the absolute path to the file.  So far we've not had any problems with it.

```
function get_realpath() {

if [[ -f "$1" ]]
then
    # file *must* exist
    if cd "$(echo "${1%/*}")" &>/dev/null
    then
        # file *may* not be local
        # exception is ./file.ext
        # try 'cd .; cd -;' *works!*
        local tmppwd="$PWD"
        cd - &>/dev/null
    else
        # file *must* be local
        local tmppwd="$PWD"
    fi
else
    # file *cannot* exist
    return 1 # failure
fi

# reassemble realpath
echo "$tmppwd"/"${1##*/}"
return 0 # success

}
```

You can combine this with other functions get_dirname, get_filename, get_stemname and validate_path.  These can be found at our GitHub repository as [realpath-lib](http://asymlabs.github.io/realpath-lib/) (full disclosure - this is our product but we offer it free to the community without any restrictions).  It also could serve as a instructional tool - it's well documented.

We've tried our best to apply so-called 'modern Bash' practices, but Bash is a big subject and I'm certain there will always be room for improvement.  It requires Bash 4+ but could be made to work with older versions if they are still around.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a realpath utility for OS X](https://github.com/user454322/realpath) which can provide the same results as `readlink -f`.

Here is an example:

```
(jalcazar@mac tmp)$ ls -l a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jalcazar jalcazar 11  8月 25 19:29 a -> /etc/passwd

(jalcazar@mac tmp)$ realpath a
/etc/passwd
```

If you are using MacPorts, you can install it with the following command: `sudo port selfupdate && sudo port install realpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Truely platform-indpendent would be also this R-onliner

```
readlink(){ RScript -e "cat(normalizePath(commandArgs(T)[1]))" "$1";}
```

To actually mimic `readlink -f <path>`, $2 instead of $1 would need to be used.

Comment: Except R is hardly on any systems by default.  Not on Mac yet (as of 10.15) which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply pasted the following to the top of my bash scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -e

declare script=$(basename "$0")
declare dirname=$(dirname "$0")
declare scriptDir
if [[ $(uname) == 'Linux' ]];then
    # use readlink -f
    scriptDir=$(readlink -f "$dirname")
else
    # can't use readlink -f, do a pwd -P in the script directory and then switch back
    if [[ "$dirname" = '.' ]];then
        # don't change directory, we are already inside
        scriptDir=$(pwd -P)
    else
        # switch to the directory and then switch back
        pwd=$(pwd)
        cd "$dirname"
        scriptDir=$(pwd -P)
        cd "$pwd"
    fi
fi
```

And removed all instances of `readlink -f`. `$scriptDir` and `$script` then will be available for the rest of the script.

While this does not follow all symlinks, it works on all systems and appears to be good enough for most use cases, it switches the directory into the containing folder, and then it does a `pwd -P` to get the real path of that directory, and then finally switch back to the original.

Answer (score -2):

Perl has a readlink function (e.g. [How do I copy symbolic links in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420058/how-do-i-copy-symbolic-links-in-perl)). This works across most platforms, including OS X:

```
perl -e "print readlink '/path/to/link'"
```

For example:

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/c
$ ln -s a/b/c x
$ perl -e "print readlink 'x'"
a/b/c
```

Comment: This does the same as `readlink` without the `-f` option - no recursion, no absolute path -, so you might as well use `readlink` directly.

Answer (score -2):

The answer from @Keith Smith gives an infinite loop.

Here is my answer, which i use only on SunOS (SunOS miss so much POSIX and GNU commands).

It's a script file you have to put in one of your $PATH directories:

```
#!/bin/sh
! (($#)) && echo -e "ERROR: readlink <link to analyze>" 1>&2 && exit 99

link="$1"
while [ -L "$link" ]; do
  lastLink="$link"
  link=$(/bin/ls -ldq "$link")
  link="${link##* -> }"
  link=$(realpath "$link")
  [ "$link" == "$lastlink" ] && echo -e "ERROR: link loop detected on $link" 1>&2 && break
done

echo "$link"
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what I use:

`stat -f %N $your_path`

Comment: This doesn't print the full path.

Answer (score -6):

The paths to readlink are different between my system and yours.  Please try specifying the full path:

> `/sw/sbin/readlink -f`

Comment: And what - exactly - is the difference between /sw/sbin and /usr/bin? And why do the two binaries differ?

Comment: Aha .. so fink contains a replacement for `readlink` that is gnu compatible. That's nice to know, but it doesn't solve my problem, since I need my script to run on other peoples machine, and I can't require them to install fink for that.

Comment: You are not answering the original question. Please rewrite your answer.