# Relative paths based on file location instead of current working directory

Tags: bash, shell

Given:

```
some.txt
dir
 |-cat.sh
```

With cat.sh having the content:

```
cat ../some.txt
```

Then running `./cat.sh` inside `dir` works fine while running `./dir/cat.sh` on the same level as `dir` does not. I expect this to be due to the different working directories. Is there an easy way to make the path `../some.txt` relative to the location of `cat.sh`?

Comment: This is BashFAQ #28: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028

Comment: This is a variant of a very frequently asked question (that being how to determine the location of a script being run). I'm pondering whether it is in fact different enough to not be a duplicate.

Comment: ...so, given the location the script is stored in (per the answer this is marked duplicate of), one need only cd to that directory before continuing to have the effect requested here.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

What you want to do is get the absolute path of the script (available via `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`) and then use this to get the parent directory and `cd` to it at the beginning of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
parent_path=$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )

cd "$parent_path"
cat ../some.text
```

This will make your shell script work independent of where you invoke it from. Each time you run it, it will be as if you were running `./cat.sh` inside `dir`.

Note that this script only works if you're invoking the script directly (i.e. not via a symlink), otherwise the finding the current location of the script gets a little more tricky)

Comment: Is there a reason why you `cd` to the script directory and then call `pwd` to store it instead of just storing the result of the `dirname` directly into `parent_path`?

Comment: @Gsinti The `pwd -P` resolves any symlinks in the path, so the statement returns the canonical path.

Comment: If you get a warning that says `cat.sh: 2: cat.sh: Bad substitution`, then see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832037/how-to-get-script-directory-in-posix-sh

Comment: Tip: If one doesn't want to change the cwd, they could also use `pushd $parent_path` instead of `cd` and call `popd` after `cat`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `Bad substitution` @CameronHudson gives a link to another post, but the answer there is so long and complex :-( Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou "The POSIX-shell (sh) counterpart of `$BASH_SOURCE` is `$0`. Caveat: The crucial difference is that if your script is being sourced (loaded into the current shell with .), the snippets below will not work properly."

Answer (score 57):

[@Martin Konecny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24112741/45375) provides an effective solution, but - as he mentions - it only works if the actual script is not invoked through a *symlink* residing in a *different directory*.

This answer covers that case: a **solution that also works when the script is invoked through a *symlink* or even a *chain of symlinks***:

---

**Linux / GNU `readlink`** solution:

If your script needs to run on **Linux** only or you know that **GNU `readlink`** is in the `$PATH`, use `readlink -f`, which conveniently resolves a symlink to its *ultimate* target:

```bash
 scriptDir=$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$BASH_SOURCE")")
```

<sup>Note that GNU `readlink` has 3 related options for resolving a symlink to its ultimate target's full path: `-f` (`--canonicalize`), `-e` (`--canonicalize-existing`), and `-m` (`--canonicalize-missing`) - see `man readlink`.

Since the target by definition exists in this scenario, any of the 3 options can be used; I've chosen `-f` here, because it is the most well-known one.</sup>

---

**Multi-(Unix-like-)platform solution** (including platforms with a **POSIX-only** set of utilities):

If your script must run on any platform that:

- has a `readlink` utility, but lacks the `-f` option (in the GNU sense of resolving a symlink to its ultimate target) - e.g., **macOS**.

  - macOS uses an *older version* of the BSD implementation of `readlink`; note that recent versions of FreeBSD/PC-BSD *do* support `-f`.
- does not even have `readlink`, but has **POSIX-compatible** utilities - e.g., **HP-UX** (thanks, @Charles Duffy).

The following solution, inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/1116890/45375,
defines **helper shell function, `rreadlink()`**, which resolves a given symlink to its ultimate target in a loop - this function is **in effect a POSIX-compliant implementation of GNU `readlink`'s `-e` option**, which is **similar to the `-f` option, except that the ultimate target must *exist***.

**Note**: The function is a **`bash`** function, and is POSIX-compliant only in the sense that only POSIX utilities with POSIX-compliant options are used. For a version of this function that is *itself* written in POSIX-compliant shell code (for `/bin/sh`), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375).

- If `readlink` is available, it is used (without options) - true on most modern platforms.
- Otherwise, the output from `ls -l` is parsed, which is the only POSIX-compliant way to determine a symlink's target.
  *Caveat*: this will break if a filename or path contains the literal substring `->` - which is unlikely, however.
  (Note that platforms that lack `readlink` may still provide other, non-POSIX methods for resolving a symlink; e.g., @Charles Duffy mentions HP-UX's `find` utility supporting the `%l` format char. with its `-printf` primary; in the interest of brevity the function does NOT try to detect such cases.)
- An installable *utility* (script) form of the function below (with additional functionality) can be found as  [`rreadlink` in the npm registry](https://github.com/mklement0/rreadlink); on Linux and macOS, install it with `[sudo] npm install -g rreadlink`; on other platforms (assuming they have `bash`), follow the [manual installation instructions](https://github.com/mklement0/rreadlink#manual-installation).

If the argument is a symlink, the ultimate target's canonical path is returned; otherwise, the argument's own canonical path is returned.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Helper function.
rreadlink() ( # execute function in a *subshell* to localize the effect of `cd`, ...

  local target=$1 fname targetDir readlinkexe=$(command -v readlink) CDPATH= 

  # Since we'll be using `command` below for a predictable execution
  # environment, we make sure that it has its original meaning.
  { \unalias command; \unset -f command; } &>/dev/null

  while :; do # Resolve potential symlinks until the ultimate target is found.
      [[ -L $target || -e $target ]] || { command printf '%s\n' "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: '$target' does not exist." >&2; return 1; }
      command cd "$(command dirname -- "$target")" # Change to target dir; necessary for correct resolution of target path.
      fname=$(command basename -- "$target") # Extract filename.
      [[ $fname == '/' ]] && fname='' # !! curiously, `basename /` returns '/'
      if [[ -L $fname ]]; then
        # Extract [next] target path, which is defined
        # relative to the symlink's own directory.
        if [[ -n $readlinkexe ]]; then # Use `readlink`.
          target=$("$readlinkexe" -- "$fname")
        else # `readlink` utility not available.
          # Parse `ls -l` output, which, unfortunately, is the only POSIX-compliant 
          # way to determine a symlink's target. Hypothetically, this can break with
          # filenames containig literal ' -> ' and embedded newlines.
          target=$(command ls -l -- "$fname")
          target=${target#* -> }
        fi
        continue # Resolve [next] symlink target.
      fi
      break # Ultimate target reached.
  done
  targetDir=$(command pwd -P) # Get canonical dir. path
  # Output the ultimate target's canonical path.
  # Note that we manually resolve paths ending in /. and /.. to make sure we
  # have a normalized path.
  if [[ $fname == '.' ]]; then
    command printf '%s\n' "${targetDir%/}"
  elif  [[ $fname == '..' ]]; then
    # Caveat: something like /var/.. will resolve to /private (assuming
    # /var@ -> /private/var), i.e. the '..' is applied AFTER canonicalization.
    command printf '%s\n' "$(command dirname -- "${targetDir}")"
  else
    command printf '%s\n' "${targetDir%/}/$fname"
  fi
)
                
# Determine ultimate script dir. using the helper function.
# Note that the helper function returns a canonical path.
scriptDir=$(dirname -- "$(rreadlink "$BASH_SOURCE")")
```

Comment: `scriptDir=$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")")` to make shellcheck happy.

Comment: @iElectric: (I originally misread your comment as relating to the `rreadlink` function). Yes, [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) issues a warning when referencing a variable that is technically an _array_ without also specifying an _index_, in which case the _1st_ element is returned (here, `$BASH_SOURCE` is equivalent to `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`).
While doing so can be a pitfall, it is also a convenient shortcut, especially with variables such as `BASH_SOURCE`, where it is almost always the 1st element that is of interest.

Answer (score 26):

Just one line will be OK.

```
cat "`dirname $0`"/../some.txt
```

Comment: Same issue as Martin's answer -- needs more quotes, or this will behave very badly when `$0` contains whitespace, glob characters, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, absolutely. more quotes will be better.

Comment: The robust version of this answer: `cat "$(dirname "$0")/../some.txt"`. Note that it will still fail in 2 cases: (a) if the script itself is invoked through a symlink to the _script_ located _in a different directory_; and (b) if the script is invoked through a path containing a symlink to the script's _directory_. In both cases, `..` will NOT refer to the script directory's actual parent directory. Aside from that, when a script is _sourced_, `$0` won't work as intended; `$BASH_SOURCE` is the better choice.

Comment: Thanks, but the unquoted use of `$0` is still a problem.

Comment: In my case I had to change it to ```cd "`dirname "$0"`"``` to handle path with spaces