# bash can't find ./script1.sh when it is called from another script2.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this issue of "./script1.sh not found" when called from another script2.sh which is actually bounded to a keyboard shortcut **(control+e).**

When I press control+e the script2.sh instantly opens up a new terminal and starts performing its task, but when it has to make a call to script1.sh, it shows this error i.e: `sh: 1: ./script2.sh: not found`

it works fine when I run it manually in the terminal which is meant to be the current working directory i.e HOME, but it doesn't work when starts from the shortcuts i.e control+e, it perform half its task.

The problem is that these scripts have set different paths as 
`"./exampleProgam"` or `"./exampleScript"` and doesn't have a full path like `"/home/user/program"` or `"/home/user/script"` .

So i don't want to go throw around 70 files and manually change paths one by one to full paths like "/home/user/folder".
I will also have to write extra code in order to get the home dir path.

All these scripts and C programs are placed in one folder i.e folder1 in the home direcory: `/home/user/folder1/script2.sh` while script1.sh is placed in the

> /home/user/script1.sh

.

and where does the terminal shell opens up by default.?? becuase when i press the control+e and the program starts in the shell , it doesn't shows any path etc but just starts executing.

Comment: Don't complain that it's not working if you don't want to do it right.  You'd have to touch it anyway, because the ./ makes it a path as well, that being the current working directory.  If you JUST used names and added all directories to the PATH that might work (would open a can of worms and be an **ugly** kludge).  Just edit your scripts, potentially using sed ...

Comment: @tink  I do want to do it right and i did it right by selecting the ./ current working directory for my whole project and it runs everywhere in the filesystems, except now when i'm trying to bound the whole program to a keyboard shortcut..The real problem is that i don't know where and in which directory does the terminal shell starts when it is started and invoked by a script.??  because it starts in some unknown directory where my program files/scripts are not placed neither on the desktop neither in the home directory.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028), which is directly on-point for what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: ...indeed, I think there's an argument that this may be duplicative of [Getting the source directory of a bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within). Or, at least, with other questions that are defensibly already marked duplicate of same (ie. [Relative paths based on file location instead of current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112727/shell-relative-paths-based-on-file-location-instead-of-current-working-director?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not a duplicate but possibly ill written question by me, it is 3:25Am , my head and whole body hurts...couldn't ask it clearly and hence getting the down votes as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will edit it maybe later.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to go ahead and fix the path actually.

Or maybe you could add your code and ask for help on how to edit/modify those lines (maybe using sed, as mentioned in the comments)/

But since you have not shown your code, and if its really that hard to correct it now, maybe you can try adding `cd /home/user/script/` as the first line in your `script1.sh` file. This will change the `current directory` for further commands.

Comment: The real problem is that i don't know where and in which directory does the terminal shell starts when it is started and invoked by a script.?? because it starts in some unknown directory where my program files/scripts are not placed neither on the desktop neither in the home directory........

Comment: ......The whole program has no issues with paths at all whether runs in home or in Desktop directory or somewhere else, and as i said the program has paths specified as "./script.sh" when it has to call to a script which is located in the same directory....The problem occurs when this same program is invoked by a keyboard shortcut which automatically opens a new terminal shell, and i don't know in which directory does this shell runs.??? I didn't posted any code because it is not about code, more about binding an application to keyboard key which runs in the terminal.

Comment: well then, just add `echo $PWD` in your code and see ... I tried and noticed thats its my home dir