# Ubuntu desktop entry based on bash script: How to access external files

Tags: bash, ubuntu, zenity

I am learning bash and am working on a bash script that allows me to select a keyboard led-profile (keyboard-color-picker.sh).

The led-profiles are defined in external files (e.g. my-favorite-color-profile), placed in the same folder as the bash script itself.
Such file is accessed like this in the script:

```
g213-led -p my-favorite-color-profile;;
```

When I run the bash script from terminal inside the parent folder, everything works as expected.
As I wanted to run my bash script via launcher, I created a desktop file
~/.local/share/applications/color-picker.desktop, where the exec line points to my script:

```
Exec=/home/me/bin/keyboard-color-picker/keyboard-color-picker.sh
```

Now my problem is, when envoked via launcher, the script does not seem to access the external files anymore. The profile defined in e.g. "my-favorite-color-profile" is not loaded.

What do I need to change so that my bash script runs via launcher the same way as it runs via terminal from the folder.

Comment: You can `cd` in your script for example

Comment: Nice, it works when I cd into the absolute path of the script. Then I wanted to make it more general, but when I tried `cd $(pwd)`  instead, it again does not work when run via launcher

Comment: `$(pwd)` does not expand to the absolute path of the script

Comment: got it, so to determine the location of a script being run, I ended up using the top answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112727/relative-paths-based-on-file-location-instead-of-current-working-directory), which also worked

Comment: You may now write an answer for your own question if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying question is how to cd into the absolute path of my script, which is answered, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112727/relative-paths-based-on-file-location-instead-of-current-working-directory).