# How do I get the absolute directory of a file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a Bash script that takes an input file as an argument and reads it.
This file contains some paths (relative to its location) to other files.

I would like the script to go to the folder containing the input file, to execute further commands.

In Linux, **how do I get the folder (and just the folder) from an input file?**

Comment: Are you giving the full path to the input file or just the path relative to the current working directory?

Comment: dhm: input gives relative path, I want absolute path *minus* filename.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

To get the full path use:

```
readlink -f relative/path/to/file
```

To get the directory of a file:

```
dirname relative/path/to/file
```

You can also combine the two:

```
dirname $(readlink -f relative/path/to/file)
```

If `readlink -f` is not available on your system you can use this<sup>*</sup>:

```
function myreadlink() {
  (
  cd "$(dirname $1)"         # or  cd "${1%/*}"
  echo "$PWD/$(basename $1)" # or  echo "$PWD/${1##*/}"
  )
}
```

Note that if you only need to move to a directory of a file specified as a relative path, you don't need to know the absolute path, a relative path is perfectly legal, so just use:

```
cd $(dirname relative/path/to/file)
```

if you wish to go back (while the script is running) to the original path, use `pushd` instead of `cd`, and `popd` when you are done.

---

***** While `myreadlink` above is good enough in the context of this question, it has some limitation relative to the `readlink` tool suggested above. For example it doesn't correctly follow a link to a file with different `basename`.

Comment: Note that `readlink -f` does not work on OS X, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't want the whole path, I just want folder.  But this offers enough to be helpful:  readlink -f relativeFileLocation | xargs dirname

Comment: @EmilSit : you are right -- natively.  But you can `brew install coreutils` to get it.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4031502/1022967 .

Comment: dirname returns . if your in the same directroy. downvote.

Comment: @Karl Morisson, indeed `dirname foo` will return `.`, but this if you `cd` into it, and ask for the `pwd`, you will get the correct answer. Please explain your objection.

Comment: Please do not recommend using `${1%/*}` or `${1##*/}` as substitutes for `dirname` and `basename`. The first breaks if you give it a simple filename (`dirname foo.bar` would, correctly, be `.`), and the second breaks for a directory ending with a slash (`basename /foo/bar/`, would, correctly, be `bar`).

Comment: @CamiloMartin, you are correct, that `$(basename $1) != ${1##*/}` and `$(dirname $1) != ${1%/*}`, but `${1%/*}` and `${##*/}` complement each other well enough to work as well as `$(dirname $1)` and `$(basename $1)`, and although your comment is valid, I think it is worthwhile to make this option known too.

Comment: @ChenLevy Some people may be inclined to use it for the sake of being faster (I think `basename`/`dirname` aren't built-ins), and they'll see it working at first but suddenly breaking at some point in the future for seemingly no good reason. I'd avoid suggesting it as an option, or disclaim that it's not really a bulletproof susbtitute.

Comment: If you're going to brew install something to work around readlink differences anyway, you could use `python -c"import os; print os.path.abspath('../..')"`.  At least it's more readable than a riddle like `${1##*/}`..

Comment: hope your filename contains no spaces or tabs or new lines or * or ? or [ characters.

Comment: [@Hello71](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335964/), I updated my answer to address your concerns.

Answer (score 28):

Take a look at `realpath` which is available on [GNU/Linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html), [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=realpath&sektion=1) and [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/realpath.1), but not OpenBSD 6.8. I use something like:

```
CONTAININGDIR=$(realpath ${FILEPATH%/*})
```

to do what it sounds like you're trying to do.

Comment: realpath does an odd to me where it resolves symlinks of relative dirs

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on Mac OS

Answer (score 6):

This will work for both file and folder:

```
absPath(){
    if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
        cd "$1"
        echo "$(pwd -P)"
    else 
        cd "$(dirname "$1")"
        echo "$(pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$cat abs.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd -P)"
```

Some explanations:

1. This script get relative path as argument `"$1"`
2. Then we get *dirname* part of that path (you can pass either dir or file to this script): `dirname "$1"`
3. Then we `cd "$(dirname "$1");` into this relative dir
4. `pwd -P` and get absolute path. The `-P` option will avoid symlinks
5. As final step we `echo` it

Then run your script:

```
abs.sh your_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try our new Bash library product [realpath-lib](http://asymlabs.github.io/realpath-lib/) over at GitHub that we have given to the community for free and unencumbered use.  It's clean, simple and well documented so it's great to learn from.  You can do:

```
get_realpath <absolute|relative|symlink|local file path>
```

This function is the core of the library:

```
if [[ -f "$1" ]]
then
    # file *must* exist
    if cd "$(echo "${1%/*}")" &>/dev/null
    then
        # file *may* not be local
        # exception is ./file.ext
        # try 'cd .; cd -;' *works!*
        local tmppwd="$PWD"
        cd - &>/dev/null
    else
        # file *must* be local
        local tmppwd="$PWD"
    fi
else
    # file *cannot* exist
    return 1 # failure
fi

# reassemble realpath
echo "$tmppwd"/"${1##*/}"
return 0 # success

}
```

It's Bash 4+, does not require any dependencies and also provides get_dirname, get_filename, get_stemname and validate_path.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the above answer comes with files input with "./"  like "./my-file.txt"

Workaround (of many):

```
    myfile="./somefile.txt"
    FOLDER="$(dirname $(readlink -f "${ARG}"))"
    echo ${FOLDER}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been using readlink -f  works on linux

so

```
FULL_PATH=$(readlink -f filename)
DIR=$(dirname $FULL_PATH)

PWD=$(pwd)

cd $DIR

#<do more work>

cd $PWD
```

Comment: don't use uppercase variable names in Bash, it will one day clash with already existing variables... oh, and this day is now: did you know the variable `PWD` already exists in Bash an its value is actually the current directory? And use more quotes too.