# Normalize arbitrary file paths in bash on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, file, path

I'm looking for a way to normalize arbitrary file paths in bash, resolving `.` and `..` to their absolute values. Examples:

```
> cd /foo/bar
> normalize_path "."   
/foo/bar
> normalize_path "../baz"
/foo/baz
> normalize_path "../../folder/that/doesnt/exist/"
/folder/that/doesnt/exist
```

Notice how in the examples above, `normalize_path` returns a value **even if the path does not correspond to a real folder or file**. All previous questions about absolute or normalized paths that I've seen on StackOverflow ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915040/bash-fish-command-to-print-absolute-path-to-a-file), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577093/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-directory-of-a-file-in-bash)) assume the path points to a real file and use `realpath` or `pwd` to normalize it, but that will not work for my use case.

In other words, I'm looking for a bash function that purely manipulates paths as strings and does not actually look at the file system, similar to [File.getCanonicalPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) in Java.

Comment: Must it be solely in `bash` or could you use `readlink -m your_imaginary_path_here` or `realpath -m your_imaginary_path_here`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: I'm looking for something that runs on OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Readlink is the way to go, or in your case greadlink. It's in the GNU core utilities package. "brew install coreutils" (if you use home-brew). Then use greadlink -m ../my_silly_filename.txt like rickhg12hs said.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know `greadlink` had a `-m` parameter! I had tried `-f` as was suggested in many other answers, and it does not work if the file doesn't exist. But `-m`, AKA `--canonicalize-missing` does exactly what I want. Thanks!