# Prepend full path of file to each line of a text file

Tags: linux, bash

I am able to prepend the filename to each line in a text file named test1 with this command:

```
nawk '{print FILENAME"\,"$0}' test1
```

I would like to prepend the full path of the file to each line of the file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
nawk -v PWD=`pwd` '{print PWD"\,"$0}' Input_file
```

In above command I am considering that your Input_file is present in current directory where you are executing this command, if this command is part of any script then you could set PWD variable with it's file name or even if you are doing cd to a path before this command into a script then also this should work.

Also since I don't have nawk in my system so fair warning if `-v PWD` doesn't work please try to use `-vPWD`. Hope this helps.

**EDIT1:** Adding filename too in solution as per OP's request.

```
nawk -v PWD=`pwd` '{print PWD"/"FILENAME","$0}' Input_file
```

**PS:** If you are trying to escape comma in above then you need NOT to put `\,` in case you want to add `\,` between lines and path of Input_file then put `\\,` to escape `\` here.

Comment: Thanks!  That allowed me to print the path but I would like to also include the filename at the end of the path if you have some thoughts on that.

Comment: @Christopher: sure please check my EDIT1 now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I was wondering how to use other commands and within awk and now I know how to do that in addition to the awk commands as well.

Comment: Glad that it helped you, keep learning and keep posting/sharing knowledge. Have a happy weekend :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `readlink` should work for you.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577093/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-directory-of-a-file-in-bash/17577143#17577143)

> To get the full path use:
>
> ```
> readlink -f relative/path/to/file
> ```
>
> If `readlink -f` is not available on your system you can use this:
>
> ```
> function myreadlink() {
>   (
>   cd $(dirname $1)         # or  cd ${1%/*}
>   echo $PWD/$(basename $1) # or  echo $PWD/${1##*/}
>   )
> }
> ```

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, it would be a good idea to edit the `myreadlink` function to use
`pushd $(dirname $1) ... popd` to save the working directory and then restore it after execution.

Comment: You may want to use `pushd $(dirname $1) ... popd` to actually prevent changing the working directory in `myreadlink`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the suggestion! I'll add it to the answer!

Comment: And you will generally want `pushd $(dirname $1) &>/dev/null... popd &>/dev/null` to suppress the directory name output `:)`