# How to chop down a path in a BASH script?

Tags: linux, bash

Short version: I want to take the last two components off the results of `readlink -f` and store it in a variable using a single line of BASH script.

Long version: I would like a single line of BASH script to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable for the [EC2 command-line tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html#setting_up_ec2_command_linux). This variable stores the location of Java's *home directory*. Using the following I can get the absolute path to the `java` binary:

```
$ readlink -f $(which java)
```

On my test machine, this outputs:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

That's perfect except I need to chop off "/bin/java". I could use string replace to do this in my profile like so:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f $(which java))
export JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME%/*/*}"
```

EDITED: Now the only issue with this is that it's two lines. I've accepted an answer below that makes it one, but it still only works on Linux whereas on OS X one must run `./Commands/java_home` from this to get the *real* directory.

Extra credit: make it work on OS X (where [`readlink -f` does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))
```

Comment: Ah, I think I got it but I changed this to: `dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))`. Is that what you meant to write?

Answer (score 1):

For the Mac OS X version, try this:

```
dirname $(dirname $(perl -e "use Cwd; print Cwd::abs_path('$(which java)')"))
```

Comment: I just ran this on Lion and the output is just `/usr` so I think the Perl is not following symlinks.

Comment: Sorry @NeilC.Obremski I screwed up the escaping. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, that *works* but there's something else screwy on OS X w/ Java: it points to a folder that has no `./bin`. Instead there's a `./Commands/java_home` command that has to be run to output the real directory ... what a pain! It appears that I can't make a line of BASH script that works between Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for extracting `/bin/java`, even on MAC OSX (untested)

`echo ${JAVA_HOME##${JAVA_HOME%/*/*}}`

Comment: Thanks @jbh; I'll update my description because this *does* work for the string replace, but what I was looking for was a full command based on `which java`.

Comment: Also, I think you just meant `echo ${JAVA_HOME%/*/*}` (otherwise it outputs `/Commands/java`)