# Print full path to file from terminal?

Tags: terminal

From the terminal lets say I navigate into a directory with a file that I'd like to "print the full path to including the file name with the spaces converted to \ \". Is there a command to do this from the terminal?

The two specific things I'm having trouble with are

1. printing out the full path with the spaces converted in \ \
2. printing out the full path including the file I'm interested in

Perhaps there are some flags that can be added to the "find" command?

Comment: find "`pwd`" -name    will print the full path however, I'm not sure how to convert the " " into "\ \"

Comment: What terminal? For example: Linux bash, Windows powershell, etc.

Answer (score -1):

See `greadlink -f` in `coreutils` as described by @tomyjwu in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac)