# configuring docker in mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I want to configure docker(which is running on mac) with `DOCKER_OPTS` variable pointing to my server ip addresses .

In linux we can configure the docker file present in  `/etc/default`.

How can we achieve the same thing in mac?

Answer (score 0):

You could export `DOCKER_OPTS` as

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-g $(readlink -f /path/to/your/config/file)"
```

Since [Mac does not have `readlink -f`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031502/6309), use greadlink instead

```
export DOCKER_OPTS="-g $(greadlink -f /path/to/your/config/file)"
```