# How to get readlink -e on M1 Macs which also works when used in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I am using several bash scripts for build and deployment processes which use `readlink` with the `-e` option. Since this option is not available I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac) suggest to install `coreutils` and create a symbolink between `greadlink` and `readlink`.
This worked perfectly on my Intel mac but when I recently switch to M1 mac I realized that the path to `greadlink` and `readlink` are changed so I tried this:

`ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/greadlink /usr/bin/readlink`

Which gave me an error: `Operation not permitted`

I realised that this is because of the [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)

How can I still use `readlink -e` in my bash scripts without deactivate the System Integrity Protection?

Comment: `readlink(){ /opt/homebrew/bin/greadlink "$@"; }`

Comment: this works when I would use readlink in the terminal but not in a bash script

Comment: It is just a matter of configuring your PATH env variable and creating a script named `readlink` with the content: `exec greadlink "$@"` with the proper shebang..

Comment: This link might help: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a script named `readlink` somewhere in your `PATH` with the following content.

```
#!/bin/sh

exec greadlink "$@"
```

---

- Just make sure that the relative path of script named `readlink` comes before `/usr/bin/` since the system `readlink` is in `/usr/bin` when you run:

```
declare -p PATH
```

or

```
echo "$PATH"
```

---

An example how to do it:

Create a directory in `~/`, name it `scripts` since it will have script as contents.

```
mkdir -p ~/scripts
```

---

Edit `~/.bashrc` to include the created directory in the `PATH` env variable.

```
if [[ :$PATH: != *:$HOME/scripts:* ]]; then
  PATH=$HOME/scripts:$PATH
fi
```

---

Source `~/.bashrc`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Create a script name `readlink` inside the `~/scripts` directory with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /opt/homebrew/bin/greadlink "$@"
```

---

Make it executable

```
chmod +x ~/scripts/readlink
```

---

Check which `readlink` is the first in `PATH`

```
type -a readlink
```

Output should be something like.

```
readlink is /home/zlZimon/scripts/readlink
readlink is /usr/bin/readlink
```

---

- Note that the current work around is for a single user, or rather the user that has `scripts` directory in `PATH`, for a system wide approach one can use the path from `homebrew` or `/usr/local/` or whichever default is available for all users.